# Support for image attachment

Tags: support, images

Is it possible to allow attaching images to questions, so that we can show screenshots — where applicable — to make our questions more comprehensive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users can already do this.
[image]
Just click on this button and you can upload an image.

If it the button is missing for you you probably have to get some more reputation.

Comment: Wow! Never used that feature, but it is pretty nice! (Apple look...)